# What is the number of connected components of a continuous image of some topological space?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, connectedness

We know that continuous image of a connected space is always connected i.e continuous image of a space with one component will always have one component.

Also a space with two components (2×2 invertible matrices) can have a connected image ( to real line via trace)

But what are the other possibilities of the number of components of a disconnected space? Can It be anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of components of the image cannot be greater than that of the domain, since every component of the domain has connected image, but it can go down as much as you like, for example the Baire space $\mathcal N=\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ is totally disconnected and has uncountably many connected components, but every separable, completely metrizable space is the continuous image of $\mathcal N$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be anything, but you canot have more connected components than the original space.

Let $\{ C_1, \dots , C_n\}$ be the set of connected components of a topological space $X$.
Let $k \le n$ be any positive integer and consider $Y=\{ 1, \dots , k\}$ equipped with the discrete topology. The connected components of $Y$ are the singletons.

Consider the map $f:X \to Y$
$$f(x) = \min \{ i, k \} \ \ \ \ \ \mbox{where } \ \ x \in C_i$$
This is a continuous map whose image is $Y$, which has exactly $k$ connected components.

Answer (score 0):

Consider various continuous maps $\Bbb{Z} \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$, where both copies of $\Bbb{Z}$ have the discrete topology.  For instance, for any fixed positive integer, $n$, $f_n(z) = [z \pmod{n}]$, where the square brackets pick out the least nonnegative member of the equivalence class.  The image of $f_n$ is $n$ points.  So for each positive integer, $n$, there is a continuous map from a space with (countably) infinitely many connected components whose image is $n$ connected components.  The identity map gives countably infinitely many components from countably infinitely many.